# Android set listview adapter without erasing predefined text of text view

Tags: android, listview

i filling list view items using this piece of code:

```
   /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ShipmentListActivity.this, shipmentList,
            R.layout.activity_shipment_list_item, new String[] { 
                    TAG_MWB,
                    TAG_ORIGIN,
                    TAG_DESTINATION,
                    TAG_SHIPMENT_TYPE,
                    TAG_STATUS,
                    TAG_WEIGHT,
                    TAG_PIECES,
            }, new int[] { 
                    R.id.mwbNumbTv,
                    R.id.shipmentOriginTv, 
                    R.id.shipmentDestTv,
                    R.id.shipmentTypeTv,
                    R.id.shipmentStateTv,
                    R.id.shipmentWeightTv,
                    R.id.shipmentPieces
                    });



    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Problem is that in textviews is predefined some text and i would like to append given values to these textviews but not rewrite them, just use something like appendText method.

I know, i can do a new textviews beside of previous pre-filled textviews, but i think that append text is simplier solution.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom adapter for something like that.

But if you want to use simple adapter only then try to use different `TextViews`.

have one `TextView` for static value and another that show value for each row.

Answer (score 0):

To append

```
String appendedText = "I'm appended";
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
tv.setText(tv.getText() +" "+appendedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the string that your are going to set i the textview,just hardcode the existing value
 in another string and make a new string by adding these two strings like :

 String a = "existing text in textview";
 String b = "Stirng that you are getting from server";
 String c = a + " "+ b;
 textview.settext(c);
```